# debugging sharepoint webpart without visual studio debugging

Tags: web-part, debugging

SharePoint debugging with visual studio stop the site.
I'm looking for a way to debugging SharePoint Webpart with out stopping the SharePoint site.

Comment: Add logging in your code

Comment: I can't understand what is your purpose, would you explain more?

Comment: If you need to debug smth in production and don't want to attach w3wp, add logging in code: write records in logging SPList or in hidden literal n the page. Records may contain variable values and code stages. If it crashes write to logs exception message and stacktrace and you will error details, where it crashes and variable values

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is run with the help of worker processes and you need to attach worker processes to debugger in order to perform debugging of server side code, I think SharePoint site freezing while debugging in on is inevitable.